# React using Hooks with onChange handler for Conditional Rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have set up a Conditional Rendering of links based upon a form login. The links will conditionally render based upon my conditions, however, my onChange event handler is firing everytime that a key is pressed into my login form.

Login component:

```
const Login = ({customerLogin, setCustomerLogin}) => {

  const handleChange = event => {
    setCustomerLogin({
      ...customerLogin,
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    });
  };
```

Form event handler in Login:

```
<label htmlFor="username">Username</label>
<input type="text" name="username" onChange={handleChange} />
```

My App.js:

```
function App() {
  const [customerLogin, setCustomerLogin] = useState(null);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Navbar isLoggedIn={!!customerLogin} />
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/signup" component={Signup} />
        <Route
          path="/login"
          render={() => (
            <Login
              customerLogin={customerLogin}
              setCustomerLogin={setCustomerLogin}
            />
          )}
        />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
}
```

EDIT: Added Navbar for clarification:

```
const Navbar = ({ isLoggedIn }) => {
    return (
        <nav className="nav-wrapper">
            <div className="container">
                <Link to='/' className="brand-logo left">Cars4U</Link>
                {isLoggedIn ? <SignedInLinks/> : <SignedOutLinks/>}            
            </div>
        </nav>
    )
};
```

Comment: What do you wish to achieve here? `onChange` handlers are supposed to fire on every key

Comment: Is it necessary for anything other than error validation? I am not certain if my onChange handler is even necessary here, based upon my submit handle.

Comment: What you are referring to is uncontrolled components, @simplest. See https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html

Comment: Are you looking for the navigation bar to show once the user has submitted the form? There is a `onSubmit` callback you can use https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components

Comment: My navigation bar just shows a brand logo and and a Login link, I am trying to set that upon having a user hit my Authentication endpoint, these links change to my other links. I added my Navbar component for clarification